Disable pylint super-init-not-called / W0231 for pyi stub files specific suppressions
Is there a way to suppress specific warnings for a specific set of files in pylint?
There are a few categories of pylint errors that don't seem to make sense for .pyi stub files.  One of these is super-init-not-called / W0231 because the stub file doesn't contain any code for any method including the __init__ methods.  Another would be unused-argument / W0613.  In most of our code, we would like to just fix these warnings and have it be part of our CI/CD so entirely disabling these warnings is undesirable.  We also enjoy the other pylint verification that happens on our stub files, so ignoring the stub files is not desirable either.  There are hundreds of locations in auto-generated files, so inline suppressions would both be ugly and challenging.
Currently the best idea I have is to run the CI/CD system twice - once with the warnings disabled and once with the stub files ignored.

https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/9417 -- https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/9096
